how to click once instead of twice the data returned by my api when searching in the scrollview which maps keysopacity?
I created a modal in which I have a textinput, to carry out the search, a scrollview which instantly displays this search. the scrollview map on touchopacity and the problem is that I find myself clicking twice on a choice instead of only once, how to remedy this?
I have already tried Keyboard.dismiss() in my handleselectitem function;
add a keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} to the scrollview and even to the modal
<ScrollView  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
                                                {results?.map((result, index) => (
                                                    <TouchableOpacity   key={index} onPress={() => handleSelectItem(result)} disabled={isDisabled}>
                                                        <View >
                                                            <CustomText fontSize={14} fontWeight={"bold"} color={colors.black} style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                                                {isCity ? result.clientinfos : result.civility ? `${result.civility} ${result.nom}` : result.nom}
                                                            </CustomText>
                                                            {result.category && (
                                                                <CustomText fontSize={14}  color={colors.black} style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                                                    {result.category}
                                                                </CustomText>
                                                            )}
                                                            {result.address && (
                                                                <CustomText fontSize={14} fontWeight={'bold'} color={colors.gray} style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                                                    {result.address}
                                                                </CustomText>
                                                            )}
                                                            {result.zip && result.city && (
                                                                <CustomText fontSize={14}  color={colors.black} style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                                                    {result.zip},{result.city}
                                                                </CustomText>
                                                            )}
                                                            {result.tel && (
                                                                <CustomText fontSize={16}  color={colors.black} style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                                                    {result.tel}
                                                                </CustomText>
                                                            )}
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            <View style={styles.divider} />
                                                        </View>
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                                ))}
                                            </ScrollView>

